# javascript ensure input files not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## html code

```
<div id="signup">
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <p>
            <label>Frist Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="sufName"/>
        <p>
        <p>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="sulName"/>
        <p>
        <p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="suEmail"/>
        <p>
        <p>
            <label>Mobile Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="suMNumber"/>
        <p>
        <p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="suPassword"/>
        <p>
        <p>
            <label>Re Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="suRePassword"/>
        <p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="sign up" onclick="signup()"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

and when i press the button sign up i want to ensure that no input files is empty and if any input field is empty i will add an error message left to that input filed

## javascript code

```
function signup(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        alert('d');
        isEmptyInput(inputs[0].id);
    }
}
function addErrorMessage(element){
    clearErrorMessage();
    var error = document.createElement('span');
    error.setAttribute('class', 'errorMessage');
    error.innerHTML="select coutry first";
    element.appendChild(error);
}
function clearErrorMessage(){
    var errors = document.getElementsByClassName('errorMessage');
    for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++){
        var kk=errors[i].parentNode;
        kk.removeChild(errors[i]);
    }
}
function isEmptyInput(input){
    if(input.value===""){
        var parent = input.parentNode;
        addErrorMessage(parent);
    }
}
```

but doesn't work , even the function isEmptyInput doesn't work
a jsfiddle copy
[code](http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/h9njC/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you are using `jquery`, it can be done much easily.
2. And also you have not closed `p` tag properly.
3. First you should prevent defauld functionality since it is on submit.
4. It not good to append on each call because the number of error span will be increasing on every submit.

Change the HTML like below and try jquery.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <p>
        <label>Frist Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="sufName"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="sulName"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="suEmail"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="suMNumber"/>
         <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="suPassword"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Re Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="suRePassword"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="sign up"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

** Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var errorCount = 0;
   $('span.errorMessage').text(''); // reset all error mesaage
   $('input').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     if($this.val() === ''){
        var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text(); // take the input field from label
        $this.next('span').text(error);
        errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
      }
  });
  if(errorCount === 0){
    $(this).submit(); // submit form if no error
  }
  });
 });
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/h9njC/11/

Comment: it works on jsfiddle , but on my code doesn't work , i included jquery already , so y it doesn't work on my code ?

Comment: yesterday was the same problem , on jsfiddle i had to change the js framework to jquery  to work , but on my code how can i do that chagne ?

Comment: did you try the latest answer ???? i have updated the answer to make it much better..

Comment: if not.. include "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" in script tag in head.

Comment: are you wrapping the code within "$(document).ready(function(){" ???? I think that could be on pbm..

Comment: dku.rajkumar i have already include one , but before 6 months , is it good, or i have to update , and i hope to include it offline , cos no alway i have internet :)

Comment: i woooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooorks after addding $(docuemnt).ready, thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: but still just one thing , if there is no error , ur code doesn't submit , i see that you are wrote a code for submit if there is no error , but actually it is doesn't submit

Comment: hey i got one idea.. change the submit button to a normal button "<input type="button" class="button" value="sign up"/>
".. make the event handler as  $('.button').on('click' instead of $('form').on('submit' and then $('form').submit() in condition. let me know if i need to change the code.

Answer (score 1):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/h9njC/9/

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" onSubmit='return false;'>
```

js:

```
function signup(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    clearErrorMessage();
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        isEmptyInput(inputs[i]);
    }
    return false;
}
function addErrorMessage(element,field){
    var error = document.createElement('span');
    error.setAttribute('class', 'errorMessage');
    error.innerHTML = "select "+field+" first";
    element.appendChild(error);
}
function clearErrorMessage(){
    var errors = document.getElementsByClassName('errorMessage');
    for(var i=0;i<errors.length;i++){
        var kk=errors[i].parentNode;
        kk.removeChild(errors[i]);
    }
}
function isEmptyInput(input){
    if(input.value===""){
        var parent = input.parentNode;
        var field = parent.getElementsByTagName('label');
        addErrorMessage(parent,field[0].innerHTML);
    }
}​
```

Comment: i want to send it to the function isEmptyInput cos that id i want to to print an error message , see code

Comment: it works good , but is javascript accept function override ? i mean adderror(element) , adderror(elament,field) ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan i don't undertand, do you need to have `adderror` twice

Comment: forget the override , it is something in java , but now i used ur code exaclty just edit the isemptyinput cos i don't want to send field.innerhtml , see the code http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/TztvN/

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function () {
    var err = false;
    $(this).closest("form").find("input[type='text']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            addErrorMessage(this); //or any other error handling you like                
            err = true;
        }
    });
    return !err;        
});
```

i wrote a [jquery plugin for form validation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easyvalidator/). check it out.
hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using a submit button.

Either add your code to the form's `OnSubmit()` event and return false on validation failure, or change your button to a regular button `type='button'` and then call `document.forms[0].submit()` within your `signup()` method when validation suceeds.

Comment: but the function signup works and i alter some test and it works

Comment: The problem is that you're using a SUBMIT button which will call the form's OnSubmit event AND you're executing the signup method.  The OnSubmit event WILL submit the form regardless of the call to signup.